# How do I create a an annualized growth rate for GDP column in my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I basically want to apply this formula: ((New/Old)^4 - 1) * 100. To a data frame I have and create a new column called "Annualized Growth Rate"
I have been working off of the FRED GDP data set.

I have a data set that looks something like this (not the real numbers)

| Index | GDP |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 103 |
| 3 | 107 |

I want to add a column on the right that applies the formula I mentioned above so that the annualized growth rate numbers would start appearing in the index = 1 position

| Index | GDP | Annualized_Growth_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | NaN |
| 1 | 101 | 4.060 |
| 2 | 103 | 8.159 |
| 3 | 107 | 16.462 |

How can I go about doing this.  I was originally trying to do it using  iterrows()
Something like

```
for index,row in iterrows():


   df['Annualized Growth Rate'] = df['GDP'].loc[index] / df.['GDP'].loc[index - 1]...
```

but then index position -1 is out of range.

I'm assuming there is an easy way to go about this that I just don't know. I also know you aren't really supposed to use something like iterrows.

Comment: Just adding a condition "if index!=0" should work I guess if you want to solve the index position -1 is out of range issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shift` to access the previous row and vectorial operations for subtraction, division, power, multiplication:

```
df['Annualized_Growth_Rate'] = df['GDP'].div(df['GDP'].shift()).pow(4).sub(1).mul(100)
```

Output:

```
   Index  GDP  Annualized_Growth_Rate
0      0  100                     NaN
1      1  101                4.060401
2      2  103                8.159184
3      3  107               16.462528
```